# iOS open app not in whitelist

Tags: ios, objective-c

Currently I want to make an app that other app can auth login by opening my app, just like Facebook do. App A click login by MyApp, A app open MyApp, then MyApp auth the app and go back to app A.

Obviously A app should add my app scheme to its whitelist and use `openURL:` function to open MyApp but how can I go back to app A when I finish auth? I don't think Facebook have all the apps in its whitelist because there are thousands of apps using Facebook login.

Someone know the answer? Thanks.

Comment: This is not possible, only Facebook can do it

Comment: you could ask the other app to include a call back url as a parameter when opening your app. you can then use that ulr to switch back.

Comment: I don't think so, because there are a lot apps can do this, not only Facebook

Comment: Facebook don't need all apps be in their whitelist. Because apps add Facebook's scheme URLs under `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes`. When Facebook authenticates user it uses them to go back to the app. Integrated SDK will handle only those callbacks that are valid for your app with a help of parameters passed with callback URL

Comment: You are looking for something like https://oauth.net/2/ I think. Google how to  implement an OAuth2 server.

Answer (score 0):

Actually `openURL:` ignores `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes`.
Check for whitelisted URL performed in `canOpenURL:`.
So just open callback url, don't perform check.